# How do I place a D3 tooltip inside a div?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to control the placement of a D3 tooltip so that it falls inside a specific div; and can thus be placed appropriately with `position: absolute`.

However, it seems like no matter how I layout the code for the svg element, the div classes for the tooltips are falling outside (after) the parent div. Thus the absolute positioning becomes relative to the page, which I do not want.

I've tried several variations of placing the div tags in different places.  I have also tried placing the tooltips inside the parent div by adding `d3.select("outline").tip();` but that throws an error.

Here is the full code I am currently using.  I'm trying to place the upper tooltip inside the right corner of the div "#outline".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

#outline {
    width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.d3-tip2 {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip2.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body><br><br><br><br><br><br><div id="outline">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = 
    [
        {letter:"A", frequency2:.08167},
        {letter:"B", frequency2:.01492},
        {letter:"C", frequency2:.02780},
        {letter:"D", frequency2:.04253},
        {letter:"E", frequency2:.12702},
        {letter:"F", frequency2:.02288},
        {letter:"G", frequency2:.02022},
        {letter:"H", frequency2:.06094},
        {letter:"I", frequency2:.06973},
        {letter:"J", frequency2:.00153},
        {letter:"K", frequency2:.00747},
        {letter:"L", frequency2:.04025},
        {letter:"M", frequency2:.02517},
        {letter:"N", frequency2:.06749}
    ];

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency2:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency2 + "</span>";
  })

var tip2 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip2')
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Other Variables:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency2 + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("#outline").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);
svg.call(tip2);

data.forEach(d=>{
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
});

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency2; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency 2");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency2); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency2); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tip.show(d);
          tip2.show(d)
          .attr("position", "absolute")
          .style("top", "16px")
          .style("left","860px");
        }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tip.hide();
          tip2.hide();
        });

function type(d) {
  d.frequency2 = +d.frequency2;
  return d;
}

</script>
</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:** I need to accomplish this by placing the tooltip inside the div, so that it moves relative to the outline.  I cannot use absolute positioning relative to the page, as this SVG block will be placed in different positions on different pages.

Comment: I think I got what you need check my solution please~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `d3.tip()` div is appended to `document.body`.

There *should be* a `d3.tip()` solution, which is [tip.rootElement](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/docs/positioning-tooltips.md#tiprootelementfunctionnode):

> You can also specify the root element, which is document.body by default.

However, `tip.rootElement` is not working, it gives `tip.rootElement is not a function` error (full disclosure here: I don't know why and I don't care, I never used `d3.tip()`, because I make my own tooltips in my projects).

**Solution**: using `createDocumentFragment`, we can move the tooltip to the desired div (look at the source and destination's IDs):

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById('sourceID'));
document.getElementById('destinationID').appendChild(fragment);
```

Here is your working code (I put a *Lorem ipsum* at the top): http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/d127ae48bbd8eb1c8050c0e3b417c251/

Comment: Once again, thank you Gerardo!  I had actually tried `top.rootElement` as my very first solution but could not figure out why it was coming back as undefined.  Now I know.

Comment: Yes, it's giving an error. You can notify the developer, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code as you can see the tooltip is inside of the `outlineParent` div.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

data = 
    [
        {letter:"A", frequency2:.08167},
        {letter:"B", frequency2:.01492},
        {letter:"C", frequency2:.02780},
        {letter:"D", frequency2:.04253},
        {letter:"E", frequency2:.12702},
        {letter:"F", frequency2:.02288},
        {letter:"G", frequency2:.02022},
        {letter:"H", frequency2:.06094},
        {letter:"I", frequency2:.06973},
        {letter:"J", frequency2:.00153},
        {letter:"K", frequency2:.00747},
        {letter:"L", frequency2:.04025},
        {letter:"M", frequency2:.02517},
        {letter:"N", frequency2:.06749}
    ];

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .attr('id', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency2:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency2 + "</span>";
  })

var tip2 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip2')
  .attr('id', 'd3-tip2')
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Other Variables:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency2 + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("#outline").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);
svg.call(tip2);


// Moving tooltips
document.getElementById('outlineParent').appendChild(
  document.getElementById('d3-tip')
);
document.getElementById('outlineParent').appendChild(
  document.getElementById('d3-tip2')
);

data.forEach(d => {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency2;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency 2");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency2);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency2);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    tip.show(d);
    tip2.show(d)
      .attr("position", "absolute")
      .style("top", "16px")
      .style("left", "860px");
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tip.hide();
    tip2.hide();
  });

function type(d) {
  d.frequency2 = +d.frequency2;
  return d;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

#outlineParent {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #FFA500;
}

#outline {
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */

.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style northward tooltips differently */

.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.d3-tip2 {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* Style northward tooltips differently */

.d3-tip2.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>

<div id="outlineParent">
  <div id="outline">
  </div>
</div>
```